# UrlFetchApp can't get past oauth 2.0 redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, oauth-2.0, fetch, google-apps-script

I have written a webservice in java based on Google App Engine, which stores and retrieves information about the ranking of a given page.

I added Oauth authentication because this service should not be available outside of our company.
The authentication and storing/retrieving data works just as it should.

The problem occurs when I try to fetch this data using Google Apps Script Function UrlFetchApp.

Instead of returning the JSON encoded data as expected it returns some HTML from a google authentication page with the title "Google Accounts".

I believe this is due to the redirect oauth requires to return the data.
My Question is now how do I retrieve my data using apps script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script doesn't support OAuth2 at this time.

Comment: Ok, thx for this answer. I am trying an alternative authentication method **without** the need for the user to login manually everytime. Any Suggestions?

Comment: OAuth 1.0 is supported by UrlFetchApp, using the OAuthConfig class.